# Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

Keep getting call method error and not sure what else to try. I have this working in another program, but not within an ajax function. I have tried putting close in 'close', "close", but still no luck. Trying to make it when the user clicks outside the dialog modal that it will close the current open modal.

```
function viewForm(record_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/info_notifications/fetch_pending_changes",
        data: "_unique_id=" + record_id,
        success: function (msg) {
            document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = msg;
            var closedialog;
        function overlayclickclose() {
            if (closedialog) {
                $('#dialog').dialog('close'); //<--this is the method its attempting to call
            }

            //set to one because click on dialog box sets to zero 
            closedialog = 1;
        }
        $('#open').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog("open");
            closedialog = 0;
        });

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            resizable: true,

            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            open: function () {
                closedialog = 1;
                $(document).bind('click', overlayclickclose);
            },
            focus: function () {
                closedialog = 0;
            },
            close: function () {
                $(document).unbind('click');
            },
            closeText: "Close",
            buttons: {
                "Update": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/info_notifications/update_notification",
                        data: "_unique_id=" + record_id,
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                                location.reload(true);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },
                "Approve": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/info_notifications/approve_request",
                        data: "_unique_id=" + record_id + "&status=approve",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                                location.reload(true);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },
                "Deny": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/info_notifications/approve_request",
                        data: "_unique_id=" + record_id + "&status=deny",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                                location.reload(true);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    click: $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                $(document).unbind('click');
            }
        });

    }

});
var closedialog;

function overlayclickclose() {
    if (closedialog) {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close'); //<--this is the method its attempting to call
    }

    //set to one because click on dialog box sets to zero 
    closedialog = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: you're trying to close the dialog before you initialize it. fix your logic.

Comment: putting closing logic at the end I still get the same error, unless you I've put the edited version of the code on here. Unless this isn't what you mean.

Comment: Why do you need the `overlayclickclose()`? Why can't you just use `$('#dialog').dialog('close');` whenever you need to close the dialog?

Comment: Where you define the function isn't important. What's important is that you are somehow *executing* the function before you initialized the dialog.

Comment: Try  `$('#dialog').dialog().dialog('close');`